# How to hide format menu in RichTextbox?

Tags: uwp

The format menu of the RichTextBox hides the wrong spelling options menu like shown below. I want to hide the format menu in RichTextbox, How to do this? My app's target version is: 1903 (build 18362), device info attached.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried the RichEditBox in my side, but the format menu shows correctly with the spelling options menu. The spelling option menu shows next to the format menu when I click the proofing button in the format menu, May I know what is the OS version of your device and what's the target version of your app?

Comment: I have added the details in my question

Comment: I made a test again in a device with 1903. But it still works correctly. Could you please tell me the detailed step that how you could reproduce this issue? Does this issue happen in every project?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved automatically in the update. It is displayed like this.

[image]